# Seeking example of how to use nntp package

Tags: haskell, monads, nntp

I still quite new to the whole monad/IO thing, and I am having trouble using the [nntp package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/nntp).
Could someone show me an example of how to use it please?
eg. How to get a list of article IDs of a group within the last 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure precisely which part of the problem you're stuck with (unless it's just "where the heck do I start?")

Looking at the documentation, it appears that the `nntp` package doesn't actually support header parsing, which seems bizarre. So you can ask it to fetch an article for you, but then *you* would have to figure out how to parse the headers to work out when the article was posted...

It looks like you can do something like

```
main = do
  articles <- runNntpWithHost "nntp.example.com" Nothing main2
  ...do stuff with articles...

main2 post_allowed = do
  group <- groupFromName "example.group"
  forArticles group return
```

to grab a list of all the articles in a given group. Not sure how you'd do anything more complex with this particular package...

Comment: I was a bit like "where the heck do I start?" at first, then I managed to get something similar to what you have shown me to compile. But when I ran it, it just sat there and not do anything. I know the server is active because it works if I do the same thing in python. Are you aware of any other nntp library in haskell?

Comment: @ePak I don't see anything else on Hackage, which is surprising. If you're running on Windows, you might need to call `withSocketsDo` to get network I/O to work.

Comment: Was doing this on a mac and tried it with `withSocketsDo`, still no luck. May be I will dig into the internal once I have gotten better with haskell. Thanks anyway.